# how to use multiple coded ui test map

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I need to use multiple coded UI test map to separte the action and to enable working in parallel.
but when I try using multiple coded ui test map, I can not find the control.
 you can find below the scenario.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateDocumentUiTest()
    {
        LoginScenario();
        var bw = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(_proc);
        bw.NavigateToUrl(new Uri("http://localhost:48387/#!/Region/Editor/"));
        UiMap1.InitializeRegionName(); //line 7
        UiMap.ClickSave();
        UiMap.ClickRefresh();
        UiMap1.IsRegionNameCorrect();
        LogoutScenario();
    }
    public UIMap UiMap => _map ?? (_map = new UIMap());
    private UIMap _map;
    public UIMap1 UiMap1 => _map1 ?? (_map1 = new UIMap1());
    private UIMap1 _map1;
```

In line 7 I used another UIMap, but it can not find the control.
is there a problem with my code. because when i record the same step with one Coded UImap it is succeed. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

may be the problem is these lines of code

```
var bw = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(_proc);
bw.NavigateToUrl(new Uri("http://localhost:48387/#!/Region/Editor/"));
```

when I record them with the new ui map the scenatio success.